# Generate git COMMIT_EDITMSG text content, but do nothing else

Tags: git, git-commit, git-status, commit-editmsg

When you run `git commit` without the `-m` flag.... `git` does ***all*** of these things for you:

1. Generates some content based on the current state of the working dir to display in your editor, with a `#` prefix on each line, as this info shouldn't go into be in the commit message when you exit your editor
2. Saves this generated content to a file named `COMMIT_EDITMSG`
3. Opens your `$EDITOR` with the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file
4. When you exit your editor, it immediately commits

Is there a command that simply only does:

- #1 above
- And then prints that text content to `STDOUT` -or- writes it to a custom filename that I specify
- ...but does ***nothing*** else?

I guess there's the option to just run `git status` and write some text transformation code to insert the `#` prefixes etc... but if there's just a simple command that does exactly #1 for me, in the exact same format as `git commit` would have done it, that would be cool.

I need to be able to do this on both Windows + Linux.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is your use-case?

Comment: @knittl I've got my own workflow tooling that already does #2, #3, #4, and a bunch of other stuff, including more interactive stuff in between #3 and #4 before committing.  I've already got some other content that I generate for #1, but now I want to add git's default COMMIT_EDITMSG content in there too.

Answer (score 2):

You can "trick" `git-commit` to do it for you:

```
GIT_EDITOR=false git commit ; cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```